# Subview Has Size Miscalculated on Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I have the below issue:

[image]

This happens on certain screen sizes only. This view is in a nib linked to a separate file listed here:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FooterActionView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIButton!

    let nibName = "FooterActionView"

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

}
```

I have confirmed that the constraints on the storyboard are completely correct (and wouldn't result in this miscalculation of the view width).
This view is subclassed from another view controller as follows:

Where can I look to see what's causing this? (Again I'm fairly certain it's not the constraints). I tried googling this but couldn't find anything that seemed to explain it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying

```
    view.frame = self.bounds
```

at a time when we do not yet know what `self.bounds` is. Then the constraints kick in and the bounds of `self.bounds` change. But the frame of `view.frame` doesn’t.

A simple solution would be to give your `view` the ability to resize itself when `self.bounds` changes:

```
    view.frame = self.bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Or you could wait until `layoutSubviews` to set `view.frame`.

Comment: So when is the right time to call that method? I copied this from an online tutorial for subclassing UI components.

Comment: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/reusable-uiviews-in-swift-3f9dca63eaf4

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is when a view obeys its constraints and does layout.

Comment: Or use autoresizing, or even autolayout, so that `view.frame` is always the right size.